# jQuery functions not triggering in casperjs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

Casperjs not triggering jQuery function or not even submitting the form or clicking submit button using these functions:

```
casper.evaluate(function() {
     // form ID
     $('#credentials').submit();
});
```

**OR**

```
casper.evaluate(function() {
     // Submit Button Class
     $('.signInButtonSmall').click();
});
```

**OR**

```
casper.then(function(){
     // Click using casperjs function
      this.click('.signInButtonSmall');
})
```

Comment: does writing any console message shows something?

Comment: yes `console.log()` works fine

Comment: ohh but that's not the problem.. i typed it wrong here only

Comment: is there any javascript errors seen in Console tab? If was errors, javascript is disabled for page.

Comment: No there are no errors

Comment: Have you taken a screenshot to see if you're on the correct page? Which PhantomJS version do you use? Please register to the `consoleMessage`, `error`, `resourceError`, `resourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-4_horsemanerrors-js)). Maybe there are errors. PhantomJS 2.x is known to hide some errors, so try PhantomJS 1.9.8.

Comment: Done that checked all errors, used `document.getElementById().click` for clicking and made some customization in code and that worked